# Generate random matrix with values that are either -1 or +1: Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a for-loop in which I want to set the matrix values either to +1 or -1

My code looks like this:

```
for n=1:512
    for m=1:512
        A(n,m)= randi([-1 1]);
    end
end
```

But right now the values are either +1,0,-1 and not just +1 or -1.

Also there should be equal probability that it is +1 or -1.
Is there a function in Matlab where you can determine that?

Comment: Why do you generate the random values one-by-one rather than generating the entire 512x512 array at one time? Are you doing something else to the values in the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all randi([imin,imax]) returns a  integer drawn from the discrete uniform distribution on the interval [imin,imax], so, in other words, it return -1 or 0 or 1 so that is why you get 0 too.

second you can omit 0 by changing your code like this:

```
for n=1:512
  for m=1:512
    A(n,m)= randi([0 1])*2-1;
  end
end
```

Comment: as i told randi([imin,imax]) produce integer numbers between  imin and imax, so when i put [0 1] as input in produce 0 and 1 . you want -1 and 1 so i just double it and Subtraction 1

Answer (score 3):

To generate a random number that equals `-1` or `1` with equal probabilities:

1. Generate a number uniformly distributed on the interval (0,1) (using `rand`) and compare with 0.5. This gives `false` (`0`) or `true` (`1`) with the same probability.
2. Multiply by `2` and subtract `1` to convert `0`, `1` to  `-1`, `1`.

So:

```
result = 2*(rand<0.5)-1;
```

Or, if you want to generate the whole matrix at once:

```
A = 2*(rand(512,512)<0.5)-1;
```

Answer (score 2):

use [`randsample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html) to sample from population (in your case `[-1,1]`):

```
% this is sampling from uniform distribution
k = 1;
y = randsample([-1 1],k,true);
```

and in your case:

```
k = 512*512;
A = reshape(randsample([-1 1],k,true), [512 512]);
```

you can use `y = randsample([-1 1],k,true,w)` to sample from arbitrary distribution:

```
% this is sampling from distribution where p(x=-1) = 0.2 and p(x=1) = 0.8
k = 1;
w = [0.2,0.8];
y = randsample([-1 1],k,true,w);
```

Comment: i get an error that "randsample" is an undefined function. My matlab-version is R2016a. maybe too old?

Comment: `randsample` exists since 2006a but is a part of the statistics toolbox.